# Using .sortInPlace within a .forEach closure Swift

Tags: swift

I am attempting to sort the arrays within a dictionary, but am getting an error.  Here is the code I have tried.  What am I missing & why won't this compile?

```
var dict = [Int: [String]]()

dict[1] = ["Zack", "James", "Bill", "Quin", "Mike", "Adam"]

dict[1]?.sortInPlace()


dict.forEach{$0.1.sortInPlace()} // error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type '[String]'
```

Edit:  I was able to get the following code to work after realizing that the for each loop assigns a constant by default:

```
db.forEach{db[$0.0] = $0.1.sort()}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift, by default assigns each value inside closure to be immutable. You can modify the default behavior by declaring the variable as mutable using **var** as this,

```
dict.forEach({ (key: Int, var value: [String]) in
    value.sortInPlace() 
    print(value)
})
```

Comment: 'var' parameters are deprecated and will be removed in Swift 3.